# Is it legal to post a modified free android app on my website?

Tags: android, legal

I am trying to do outside projects during college as part of self-learning, and trying to boost my resume/portfolio for internships. Recently I taught myself how to modify the temple run apk to give myself unlimited coins, but in doing so i had to resign the apk with my own certificate.

If i wanted to post this online, and possibly write up a blog post about it, would it be legal? I assume it would be legal if i just wanted to talk about it and how i did it, but is posting the file okay too?

Comment: It depends. If the app is open-source, it's fine as long as you follow the license (typical requirements: credit original authors, release your code under the same license).

Comment: If not, you can post a patch. However, if what you do actually works around access restrictions, the DMCA forbids sharing it (U.S. law).

Comment: Ah thank you for your fast reply. I guess I will just talk about it in a blog post then. Is it illegal that the app gives you free coins, since the only other two ways to earn coins are by playing the game or buying them?

Comment: Not sure. The relevant provision is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-circumvention one.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely.  It will depend on whether or not the author has licensed it with a license that allows distribution of derivative works (e.g. the GPL, or a Creative Commons license).  If it doesn't say so on the apps page, then you should assume not, and contact the author for permission.